# HelloAndroid.java not created automatically - Hello World Android App in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've finally installed the Android SDK/Eclipse and set everything up correctly (I thought), but when I create a new Android project it is not automatically creating the necessary files (HelloAndroid.java is missing).

I just wanted to do the simple [HelloAndroid example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) to verify that everything was properly set up, and obviously I can add the file myself, but my settings are all defaults and I don't understand why this file would not be created for me when every tutorial assumes it is. In fact I cannot find any posts from others about this issue, either.  The HelloAndroidActivity.java file *is* created, however.

Any ideas why this file is not being created for me? Did I start a new project the wrong way?  I am using Eclipse on OSX 10.7.3.

Comment: Xi Zhang is correct. Step 3 in creating the project in the link you gave shows..."Create Activity: HelloAndroid". It seems you gave it the name "HelloAndroidActivity` instead. Right-click on `HelloAndroidActivity.java` in the Eclipse Package Explorer pane and choose Refactor then Rename to rename it to `HelloAndroid.java`

Answer (score 1):

It's HellowWorld.java or HelloWorldActivity.java depends on what you choose at this step. Whatever the name is, as long as the it extends Activity Class you should be OK.

[image]

Comment: oh, wow, that's embarrassing - I thought it was completely different and didn't bother to compare the code.  Thank you

Comment: @tcwct Always glad to help. Do you want to accept my answer? I see you are new to SO.... just like the check mark next to my answer.